# Promise não executa .then()

Tags: javascript, promises

Bom dia, preciso de ajuda com minha promise, ao gravar minhas informações no indexDB estou utilizando o .then para escrever no console, porem esse .then não é disparado.

Notei que minha promise fica com status pending e não sei se isso tem haver.

```
//codigo executado no console

const negociacao = new Negociacao( new Date(), 7, 100);

ConnectionFactory
                .getConnection()
                .then(conn => new NegociacaoDAO(conn))
                .then(dao => dao.adiciona(negociacao))
                .then(() => console.log('sucess'))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

a classe NegociacaoDAO é a classe responsavel por adicionar os itens no indexDB e retornar esta promise

```
class NegociacaoDAO{

    constructor(connection){

        this._connection = connection;
        this._store = 'negociacoes';

    }

    adiciona(negociacao){

        return new Promise( (resolve, reject)=>{
            const request = this._connection
                                        .transaction([this._store], 'readwrite')
                                        .objectStore(this._store)
                                        .add(negociacao);

            request.onsucess = e => resolve(e.target.result);

            request.onerror = e => {
                console.log(e.target.error);
                reject('Não foi possivel salvar a negociação');
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: ```request.onsucess``` não seria ```request.onsuccess``` ?

Comment: Obrigado Artur, sou iniciante e estou desde ontem com esse problema.

Comment: Sem problemas. Se isso resolveu seu problema, não esqueça de aceitar a resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o problema está nessa linha:

```
request.onsucess = e => resolve(e.target.result);
```

Está faltando um 'c'. Assim o callback nunca vai ser chamado, e a Promise nunca vai ser resolvida. O correto seria:

```
request.onsuccess = e => resolve(e.target.result);
```